# libraries in python and upnp

Tags: python, service, upnp, service-discovery

I want to develop some protocols that helps in the functioning of UPNP(universal plug and play) and simple service discovery protocol. I need to find the libraries for python and upnp so that I can read them and it becomes easy for me to understand when i used them. Please provide me the links for it.

Answer (score 2):

[MiniUPnP](http://miniupnp.free.fr/) is a popular UPnP library with Python hooks. For Python libraries, look in the Python distribution. Mine are in `/usr/lib/python2.6` and `/usr/lib/python3.1`. There are libraries galore to read there.

Comment: How do I use the MiniUPNP library with python? I mean- how do i install itwith my opython. I have installedpython 2.7 on My PC.

Comment: @KIT The man page of miniupnp has demonstrated the interface for how using the library, which can be invoked from python via ctypes, but of course there are upnp clients implemented in pure python. I googled around and couple of candidates came out.